# PHPMailer not sending

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to create a contact form using PHP mailer..
it shows no error but I do not receive the email. I also tried to use the mail() function but it also not working..

Here's my PHP code

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
$errors = array();
$to = "kim@t-i-c.asia";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$body = $_POST['message'];
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$email;

    require_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    // Set UP SMTP
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure ='ssl';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    //Authentication
    $mail->Username = "kuyakimpoy010@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom ("client@t-i-c.asia", $email);
    $mail->AddReplyTo("client@t-i-c.asia", $email);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHtml($body);
    $mail->addAddress($to,'Kim Carlo'); //recipient
    $mail->Send();

    if($mail){
        $errors = "<font style='font-size:18px; color:#000000; line-height:150%'>Thank you!<br><br></font><font style='font-size:16px;''>We have received you message.<br>Your opinions and comments are very important to us and we read every message that we receive.<br>Our goal is to improve our service in any way we can, and we appreciate your taking the time to fill<br>
        out our feedback form.<br><br></font>";
    }else{
        $errors = "<font style='font-size:18px; color:#000000; line-height:150%'>There was a problem sending your message.<br><br>Please try again later.</font>";

    }
    header("refresh:10; url=/../contactform.php");
}else{
$errors = "<font style='font-size:18px; color:#000000; line- height:150%'>Please fill in email address and message fields<br><br></font>";
}

?>
```

here is my contact form

```
<form name="contact" method="POST" action="php/feedback.php">
            <label>Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>

            <label>Email Address:<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email"/><br><br>

            <label>Subject:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="subject"/><br><br>

            <label>Message:<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
            <textarea cols="45" rows="10" name="message"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
```

Comment: are you trying on localhost?

Comment: no.. i'm on a web server.. hostinger..

Comment: have you done smtp configuration?

Comment: should I configure it on the web server??

Comment: it's working on the localhost but not on the web server..

Comment: I see 2 possibilities: for google port I have used 587 and always was working, 2. check if the restricted access is disabled on your gmail, if it is active and it is the problem, then google will mail you for the same

Comment: Looks like you have based your code on an old example, so you're probably using an old version of PHPMailer too. Get latest video and examples from GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing this line..

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
```

thanks for the time guys...